# Store Hbm.xml in folder, Load them on demand

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

What is the best way to store hbm files separately from entity assembly, and load them on demand? I assume I need to load xml file into `HbmMapping` instance and serialize it into `Hibernate.Cfg.Configuration` instance?

Comment: What do you mean by "on demand"?  You should create NHibernate Session Factory once at application start.  After you've created it, I don't think you can modify it.

Comment: Thats true, on-demands=once, but after I do some modification to that xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly)` is one of the more commonly used methods for loading *.hbm.xml mappings, but it's not the only one.  These are all of the "add mappings" methods:

- `AddAssembly`
- `AddClass`
- `AddDeserializedMapping`
- `AddDirectory`
- `AddDocument`
- `AddFile`
- `AddInputStream`
- `AddMapping`
- `AddResource`
- `AddUrl`
- `AddXml`
- `AddXmlFile`
- `AddXmlReader`
- `AddXmlString`

Assuming you have a method named `Stream OpenHbm(String)`, I believe something like this should work:

```
foreach (var hbmName in hbmNames)
    using (var stream = OpenHbm(hbmName))
        config.AddInputStream(stream, hbmName);
```